# insert null for DATETIME Field through PrepareStatement using jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, prepared-statement

i want to insert null value into an DATETIME Field through PrepareStatement using JDBC (using Mysql Database) i have tried following ways but nothing is worked.

i have a method " Util.dateconvertdate " it use to convert input date into a formatted string type

```
public static String dateconvertdate(Timestamp timestamp) {
            Date date=null;
            String formattedDate="";
            if(timestamp != null){
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
                 Date date1 = new java.util.Date(timestamp.getTime());
                 formattedDate = formatter.format(date1);
        }
            else return "NULL";

            return formattedDate;
        }
```

and i use to check whether it return null or date

```
if(Util.dateconvertdate(rs.getTimestamp("fld_dob")) !=null){
                    pmystmt.setString(17, (Util.dateconvertdate(rs.getTimestamp("fld_dob"))));
} else{
 pmystmt.setNull(17, java.sql.Types.NULL);
}
```

and i tried with

```
pmystmt.setNull(17, java.sql.Types.DATE);

pmystmt.setNull(17, Types.NULL);

pmystmt.setInt(17, Types.NULL);

pmystmt.setString(17, "NULL");

pmystmt.setNull(17, Types.DATE);

pmystmt.setString(17, null);

pmystmt.setDate(17, null);
```

but nothing is working it is throwing exception like

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: 'NULL' for column 'dob' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1601)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1710)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:2436)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1402)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1694)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1608)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1593)
    at com.members.App_users.AddRecords(App_users.java:66)
    at com.main.Start.main(Start.java:47)
```

any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Is the column nullable? Also, if it's a DATETIME column why are you using `setString()`?

Comment: What's the table decoration?

Answer (score 3):

If your table column is nullable then Try to use it. It may help you.

```
pmystmt.setNull(17, java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your database url include `zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull` while setting datasource.

```
jdbc:mysql://ip_address:port/databasename?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```