# MySQL Incorrect date value: null

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to update a table from a Java application where a certain column *may* be NULL. I have tried several different approaches but I always get the following error:

`com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: 'null' for column 'scheidingsdatum' at row 1`

I made sure that the table allowed NULL values for the scheidingsdatum field, and can insert NULL values when directly inserting in MySQL

This is the table structure in PHPMyAdmin:

[image: PHPMyAdmin table structure]

The tables use innoDB

I have tried the following solutions:

**1: Just use the NULL variable in a parameter**

```
stmnt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE gezinnen SET "
                            + "ouder1 = ?," 
                            + "ouder2 = ?," 
                            + "huwelijksdatum = ?,"
                            + "scheidingsdatum = ? "
                            + "WHERE gezinsNummer = ?");

stmnt.setString(1, ouder1);
stmnt.setString(2, ouder2);
stmnt.setString(3, huwelijksdatum);
stmnt.setString(4, scheidingsdatum);
stmnt.setString(5, nummer);
```

**2: Hardcode NULL in the query (inside if/else block)**

```
stmnt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE gezinnen SET "
                            + "ouder1 = ?," 
                            + "ouder2 = ?," 
                            + "huwelijksdatum = ?,"
                            + "scheidingsdatum = NULL "
                            + "WHERE gezinsNummer = ?");

stmnt.setString(1, ouder1);
stmnt.setString(2, ouder2);
stmnt.setString(3, huwelijksdatum);
stmnt.setString(4, nummer);
```

**3: Use setNull(4, java.sql.Types.DATE)**

```
stmnt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE gezinnen SET "
                            + "ouder1 = ?," 
                            + "ouder2 = ?," 
                            + "huwelijksdatum = ?,"
                            + "scheidingsdatum = ? "
                            + "WHERE gezinsNummer = ?");

stmnt.setString(1, ouder1);
stmnt.setString(2, ouder2);
stmnt.setString(3, huwelijksdatum);
stmnt.setNull(4, java.sql.Types.DATE);
stmnt.setString(5, nummer);
```

**4: Use setNull(4, java.sql.Types.NULL)**

```
stmnt = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE gezinnen SET "
                            + "ouder1 = ?," 
                            + "ouder2 = ?," 
                            + "huwelijksdatum = ?,"
                            + "scheidingsdatum = ? "
                            + "WHERE gezinsNummer = ?");

stmnt.setString(1, ouder1);
stmnt.setString(2, ouder2);
stmnt.setString(3, huwelijksdatum);
stmnt.setNull(4, java.sql.Types.NULL);
stmnt.setString(5, nummer);
```

the following is my database.properties file and connection creation:

**database.properties**

```
jdbc.drivers=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://IP:3306/TABLE_NAME
jdbc.username=USER
jdbc.password=PASSWORD
```

**Connection creation**

```
Class.forName(props.getProperty("jdbc.drivers")).newInstance();
this.conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(props.getProperty("jdbc.url"),props.getProperty("jdbc.username"),props.getProperty("jdbc.password"));
```

Comment: @YassinHajaj NULL is a special value, SQL is a 3-valued logic language. The OP wants NULL, and not some replacement for it. If you use replacement you need to remember this and modify accordingly all your queries.

Comment: @YassinHajaj Any date is theoretically possible.

Comment: @dognose That works for inserts, but what about updating it? It should be possible to change it from an actual date to null later.

Comment: Strange, if you're indeed seeing this issue, it's probably some problem with the JDBC driver. I cannot imagine that at least one of your approaches won't work.

Comment: See this. Seems related... But not useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27957727/insert-null-for-datetime-field-through-preparestatement-using-jdbc

Comment: @RealSkeptic That was also one of the solutions I tried. (The third one)

Comment: See also this. Read about this strict mode. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957421/mysql-datatime-null

Comment: Have you tried `stmnt.setDate(4, (Date)null)`?

Comment: @dognose I just tried that, same exception still :(

Comment: @RealSkeptic I updated the question with my database.properties and connection part.

Comment: @peter.petrov Disabling strict mode didn't fix it unfortunately.

Comment: Did you try to add `?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull` to the database URL as mentioned in one of the links @peter.petrov gave?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I did, but it didn't work so I removed it again.

Comment: Which method did you combine it with?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I tried both adding it to the url in the database.properties file and concatenating it with the string in the part where I create the Connection (so `props.getProperty("jdbc.url")+"?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"`)

Comment: No, I meant - which of the null-setting methods did you try when you did that?

Comment: Found a few similiar posts. most answered with "I updated the JDBC Driver, problem gone" - which version are you running on?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Oh, I combined it with `stmnt.setNull(4, java.sql.Types.DATE);`

Comment: @dognose I'm running 5.1.37, downloaded it from the MySQL site today.

Comment: Have you tried using `setDate` with a `null` `java.util.Date` object?  In your first try, you're setting the value as a `String`  Is it possible you're using the String `"null"` instead of a true `null` value?

Comment: @IanMcLaird I just tried that, didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Can you make it work from the MySQL command line client?

Comment: I fixed it because I made a dumb mistake of not properly checking the code made by someone else and making assumptions about how it would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just made a test and it worked for me with `stmnt.setNull(4, java.sql.Types.Date);`, are you sure that for  `stmnt.setString(3, huwelijksdatum);` the value of huwelijksdatum is a valid mysql date string and not "null" ?

Comment: That was indeed the issue as I explain here http://stackoverflow.com/a/33224384/4385713

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is the dumbest fix ever.

The code was originally made by someone else, and I only expanded on it a bit. They first created a string `scheidingsDatum = "null";`, which would then be overwritten by an actual date if there was one.

I *assumed* (I know, it's never smart to assume) that it would be null (Notice the lack of quotation marks?) when it didn't have a value.

So, in my check, the string wasn't null (since it was "null") and so the first part was executed. Which made it try to insert a string "null", which is obviously an incorrect date.

Simply modifying the string to be null instead of "null" upon instantiation fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You could try TIMESTAMP instead of DATE in your prepared statement.

```
stmnt.setNull(4, java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same exception when I do that, unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

If scheidingsdatum is a nullable field, then simply remove it from your UPDATE statement when its value is null. In other words, when scheidingsdatum is null, change the statement to:

```
UPDATE gezinnen SET ouder1 = ?, ouder2 = ?, huwelijksdatum = ?
WHERE gezinsNummer = ?
```

Comment: But then wouldn't it remain the same as it was before the update? Scheidingsdatum can be nulled after it's set.

Comment: Ah good point. Then in the case where scheidingsdatum is supposed to be saved as null, replace "scheidingsdatum = ?" with "scheidingsdatum = null".